# Ruby flash messages translation

Tags: ruby, internationalization

There are some locale files in our project, that look like:

```
notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully created.' 
alert: '%{resource_name} could not be created.'
```

We use I18n for translation. Now if we translate something in Russian, it looks this way:

```
notice: '%{resource_name} был успешно создан.'
```

Where %{resource_name} is default translation and is always in English. How can i translate this to other languages, using my own translation? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your resource is an Active Record model ? If so please check [this part of documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Create translation file:

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: пользователь
```

then:

```
t('notice', resource_name: User.model_name.human)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a different translation for each controller and actions, e.g.

```
en:
  posts:
    create:
      notice: "Post was successfully created"

  users:
    create:
      notice: "User was successfully created"
```

And so on

Comment: That would work, but not really a DRY nor flexible approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't know the key to models (resource_name) or i can create locale file with default structure without any dependence on resource_name?

Comment: @Александр The `resource_name` values are the model handled by your controller (probably the method is defined for each controller). Yes, you could just say something like `'Resource was successfully created.' ` (or anything along these lines that doesn't mention the specific resource created)